# mostrar 9 items each

Tags: jquery

estimados necesito listar solo 9 items de esta función lo hago con each muestra todos los contenidos como puedo limitar a 9 al cargar por primera vez
Gracias.

```
function Cargardata() {
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');

    $.getJSON('/books-schema.json', function(data) {
        var output = '<ul id="resultado">';

        $.each(data.data, function(i, item) {
            if ((item.title.search(myExp) != -1) || (item.teaser.search(myExp) != -1)) {
                output += '<li>';
                output += '<span class="image"><img src=' + item.image + '/></span>';
                output += '<span class="title">' + '<h3>' + item.title + '</h3>' + '</span>';
                output += '<span class="description">' + '<p>' + item.teaser + '</p>' + '</span>';
                output += '</li>';
            }
        });
        output += '</ul>';
        $('content').html(output);
    });

}
```

Comment: Podrías explicar a qué te refieres con _" 9 items de esta función"_? son los items dentro de `books-schema`? Si fuera así, es sobre  cargar solo 9 items del archivo, o una vez obtenido el archivo, mostrar solo 9 items en el `content`?

Comment: si solo mostrar 9 items en el content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución para hacerlo dinámico sería agregar un parámetro a `Cargardata` para que no se limíte a mostrar 9 elementos:

```
function Cargardata(count) {
  var searchField = $('#search').val();
  var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');

  $.getJSON('/books-schema.json', function(data) {
    var output = '<ul id="resultado">';

    var dataCounter = 0;

    $.each(data.data, function(i, item) {
        if ((dataCounter < count) && ((item.title.search(myExp) != -1) || (item.teaser.search(myExp) != -1))) {
          output += '<li>';
          output += '<span class="image"><img src=' + item.image + '/></span>';
          output += '<span class="title">' + '<h3>' + item.title + '</h3>' + '</span>';
          output += '<span class="description">' + '<p>' + item.teaser + '</p>' + '</span>';
          output += '</li>';
          dataCounter +=1;
        }
    });
    output += '</ul>';
    $('content').html(output);
  });

}
```

Ya con esto podrías llamar a la función con un número aleatorio de items a mostrar:

```
Cargardata(9);
```

Comment: Hay un error en esta respuesta: En caso de que la condición en el `if` sea falsa se mostrarán menos de `count` items, a pesar que hayan más de `count` en `data` que cumplan la conidición

Comment: Toda la razón @CarlosMuñoz, agregué una validación en el `if` para que se asegure de tener como mínimo de items el `count` de parámetro

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una variable `count` inicializada en `0`

```
var count = 0;
```

que vaya contando cuantos `<li>` vas agregando al `<ul>` y  en el `if` verificar que no se hayan ya 9 elementos.

```
if ((count < 9 && (item.title.search(myExp) != -1) || (item.teaser.search(myExp) != -1)))
```

Y si agregas uhn `<li>` no olvides incrementar el `count`: `count++;`

```
function Cargardata() {
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');

    $.getJSON('/books-schema.json', function(data) {
        var output = '<ul id="resultado">';

        var count = 0;
        $.each(data.data, function(i, item) {
            if ((count < 9 && (item.title.search(myExp) != -1) || (item.teaser.search(myExp) != -1))) {
                output += '<li>';
                output += '<span class="image"><img src=' + item.image + '/></span>';
                output += '<span class="title">' + '<h3>' + item.title + '</h3>' + '</span>';
                output += '<span class="description">' + '<p>' + item.teaser + '</p>' + '</span>';
                output += '</li>';
                count++;
            }
        });
        output += '</ul>';
        $('content').html(output);
    });
}
```